Populating Mixpanel "your properties"
I have an issue regarding the populating of "Your Properties", I cant populate my mixpanel with any ekstra properties, not even test data, what am I doing wrong ? 

Here is my component, the Event shows up correctly but not with any of my properties, only mixpanels own defaults properties show up
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Mixpanel from 'react-native-mixpanel';

const withEventTracking = (WrappedComponent, eventProps = {}, userEmail) => {
  return (props) => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const currentScreen = navigation.getState().routes[navigation.getState().index].name;
const trackEvent = () => {
  console.log(`Tracking event for user: ${userEmail}`); // Log the user email
  Mixpanel.track("Test Event", {
    screen: currentScreen,
    button: props.title || props.accessibilityLabel || 'Unnamed Button',
    userEmail: userEmail,
    exampleProperty: "testValue",
    ...eventProps,
    ...props.eventProps,
  });
  if (props.onPress) {
    props.onPress();
  }
};

return <WrappedComponent {...props} onPress={trackEvent} />;

};
};
export default withEventTracking;
